# postgresql script to list all functions including create date and modify date

Tags: postgresql, query, functions

I have been deploying many functions into different databases in different servers in PostgreSQL.

I would like to have a script that would show me a list of functions in the current database including their create and modify date.

I did some research but it did not get me much, that lead to this question.

[image]

Another basic question is how to find out what is the postgreSQL version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would like to have a script that would show me a list of functions in the current database*

Something like:

```
SELECT n.nspname as schema_name,
       p.proname as name,
       pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as result_type,
       pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as parameters
       CASE p.prokind
         WHEN 'a' THEN 'aggregate function'
         WHEN 'w' THEN 'window function'
         WHEN 'p' THEN 'procedure'
         ELSE 'function'
       END as type
FROM pg_proc p
   LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE n.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

> *including their create and modify date.*

That's not possible. Postgres does not store this information

> *Another basic question is how to find out what is the postgreSQL version?*

```
select version();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, just the create and modify date was what I needed most of all, as I wanted to know the list of functions I have modified today, in each server.